# Is it possible to construct an operator for $z$-component of spin for a 2D system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, spin-models

Let's say we have an arrangement of spins in 2D space (as given in the below picture).

[image]

Assume that the $z$-axis is out of the plane and a spin (circled in red) makes an angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis. This spin precesses in its direction. If it precesses of course it has some component in the $z$-direction. One can construct the $x$-(or $y$-) direction component of spin by measuring the angle $\theta$. For example, $\hat S_x = \hbar \cos \theta$ and $\hat S_y = \hbar \sin \theta$. This kind of decomposition is readily available from the already known direction of spin. But I can't see how can we measure the $z$-component of spin in this formalism. Is there any way to measure the $z$-component of spin for this kind of spin arrangement?

Comment: "If it precesses of course it has some component in the -direction." Is this true? If I hold my arms out horizontally and spin about a point on the floor, must my hands point in a direction that has a vertical component?

Comment: If the red arrow was *linear* momentum and it were precessing then I would agree that there is a z-component of *angular* momentum, but that is something else entirely.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer let me be more specific, I am actually measuring magnonic spin current $J$ in a 2D non-collinear magnet (the one given above). To measure  x-component of spin current in y-direction, I use operator $\hat J_y^x=\hat S_x \hat v_y$. And for y-component  $\hat J_y^y=\hat S_y \hat v_y$. I believe that when one particle (magnon) moves, this magnon, even though it's travelling in $xy$ plane, has some $z$-component of spin. I want a current operator for this component. I thought, if I can make an operator for $z$-component of spin, I can make current operator as $ J_y^z= S_z v_y$

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer can't I use commutation relation $\{\hat S_x,\hat S_y\}=i\hbar \hat S_z$ to get $\hat S_z$?